# Why HTML Table Is So Slow To Render in Explorer and Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, html-table

I'm working with a dynamic HTML table that has a max row count of around 7,000.  The code below shows how the current design is populating the table with rows of data.  Performance in Chrome is great but IE and Edge are terribly slow.  As you can see, the code below is basically assigning the table to the string variable "mTable". innerHTML is then called on the resulting object.  The while loop is just to insert empty rows in the event few records are returned.  The table is draggable, sortable and can be opened in a new window.  All three of those functions become incredibly slow in IE once the table grows in size.  In fact, I can actually watch the table get populated in the new window function - it's that slow.  Edge has better performance in those three areas but it still takes too much time to populate.  I've done a lot of reading about this though most of the literature just describes the problem.  There were a few ideas that mentioned setting the table's layout to fixed and having each row occupy an equal amount of space but that didn't seem to help.  I also saw some older solutions that involved running chrome inside IE but that doesn't seem like an option anymore.   I thought by sharing my code that perhaps someone might provide some insight as to a better approach.  Thank you in advance for any helpful responses.

```
    function makeTable(param1){


            paramJ = JSON.parse(param1);

            mTable="<table id='myTable' class='Table1 tablesorter rbody' style='color:RGB(255,255,255);'><thead><tr>"+
                "<th id='topRC' class='td1 tr1' onclick='resetHighlight();' style='width:20px;'></th>"+
                "<th class='td1 tr1' >OBJECTID</th>"+
                "<th class='td1 tr1' >Locomotive ID</th>"+
                "<th class='td1 tr1' >Signal ID</th>"+
                "<th class='td1 tr1' >Avg RSSI</th>"+
                "<th class='td1 tr1' >Signal Strength</th>"+
                "<th class='td1 tr1' >Count</th></tr></thead>";  
            iterTable=1;
             mTable+="<tbody id='tbodyID'>";
            for(i=0;i<paramJ.features.length;i++){

                mTable+="<tr class='rHighlight rbody' style='background-color:RGB(75,75,75);'><td class='td1 tdClick' style='width:20px;' ondblclick='resetHighlight();funGeom(this);'></td><td class='td1'>"+iterTable+"</td>";
                mTable+="<td class='td1'>"+paramJ.features[i].attributes.VAL1+"</td>";
                mTable+="<td class='td1'>"+paramJ.features[i].attributes.VAL2+"</td>";
                mTable+="<td class='td1'>"+paramJ.features[i].attributes.VAL3.toFixed(0)+"</td>";

                mTable+="<td class='td1'>"+paramJ.features[i].attributes.VAL4+"</td>";
                mTable+="<td class='td1'>"+paramJ.features[i].attributes.VAL6+"</td>";
                mTable+="</tr>";
                iterTable+=1;

                }

                while(iterTable<100){

                    mTable+="<tr class='rbody' style='background-color:RGB(75,75,75);'><td class='td1' style='width:20px;'></td><td class='td1'></td>";
                    mTable+="<td class='td1'></td>";
                    mTable+="<td class='td1'></td>";
                    mTable+="<td class='td1'></td>";
                    mTable+="<td class='td1'></td>";
                    mTable+="<td class='td1'></td>";
                    mTable+="</tr>";
                    iterTable+=1;
                }
             mTable+="</tbody></table>";
             document.getElementById("containerR2").innerHTML=mTable;

             //below is for sorting and opening table in new window
             $("#myTable").tablesorter( { headers: { 0: { sorter: false} }} ); 
             if(winOpen=="yes"){newTable();}        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking some type of primary key, such as `OBJECTID` if I'm guessing correctly, and use that as the key for a dictionary. Then use `document.createElement` to populate the dictionary with DOM elements. That will be done only once, whenever you get your data (Initial load, AJAX, etc). Now, when you do anything else, just `myTable.appendChild(tableDict[key])` over and over again to add the node to the table. That can either be sorted, or not sorted, depending on the for loop that's running over `key`s.

If you want more speed, or if my suggestion didn't help, use asyncs to separate adding things to `tableDict` and progressively putting them on myTable. I don't think this will be necessary though.